# What's the difference between 差異 and 差別?

Tags: difference, meaning

Do both of them mean "difference?" Not sure if they are the same part of speech or if they are interchangeable.

Comment: some answers seem to come up with questionable distinctions, see dictionary examples,   **差异**  ＃３４３６ difference; divergence; discrepancy; diversity:
能力(年龄)方面的差异 discrepancy in ability (age)
方言上的差异 dialectic difference
这两个地区气候差异很大。 These two regions differ greatly in climate.这对孪生姐妹性格差异很大。 The twin sisters are very different in character.
1) 差别，不同。
2) 奇异，反常。
**差别**  #4396 difference
distinction
disparity dissimilarity; distinction; unlikeness:年龄差别 disparity in age
数(质)量上的差别 quantitative (qualitative) difference
仅是口味差别 dissimilar in tastes only
社会结构上的差别

Comment: unlikeness in social structure 男女差别 disparity between men and women 毫无差别。 There is no difference at all. 二者之间差别很大。 There is a world of difference between the two. 实际上并无差别。 There is practically no difference. 二者之间差别很大。

Answer (score 4):

Both 差異 and 差別 mean "difference"

- 差異 = (physical) difference
- 差別 = (physical or metaphorical) difference

Example:

这两张牌全无**差異**/这两张牌全无**差別**  (these two cards have no difference)

*the two cards are physically the same*

对我而言，有机食品和普通食品之间並无**差别**  (to me, there's no difference between organic foods and common foods)

*the two products have the same food value to me*

> you cannot replace 差别 with 差異 here because the difference between them is not physical but of value in your opinion.

One more example for 差别 used to describe metaphorical difference:

输给彼得或输给保罗是一样的，没有什么差别 (lose to Peter or lose to Paul are the same, there's no difference)

*the main point is you lose*

> Again, you cannot use 差異 instead of 差别 here because the focus is not on the physical difference between 'lose to Peter' and 'lose to Paul' . The focus is on the win or lose result)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tang Ho's answer, one of the major difference between these 2 words is:

#### 差異 is usually used when measurement is involved.

Say if you're comparing the weather between 2 countries:

1. The weather between Canada and Africa differ greatly
   加拿大和非洲之間的天氣差別很大
2. The temperature between Canada and Africa differ greatly
   加拿大與非洲之間的氣溫差異很大

Note that some of the metaphorical differences (as mentioned from Tang) might not be as 'measurable', such as culture, knowledge, etc.

Answer (score 1):

simple to say

**差異** = difference; divergence; discrepancy; diversity; odds; variation

e.g：

气候差异
difference in climate

文化差异
cultural diversity

看法上的差异
difference of opinion

refer：https://www.jayxun.com/what/7AHT

---

**差別** = difference; division; distinction

e.g：

缩小城乡差别
narrow the gap between town and country

年龄差别
difference in age

质量与数量上的差别
qualitative and quantitative differences

你去不去没什么差别。
It makes little difference whether you go or not.

refer dict： https://www.jayxun.com/what/7AJv